# grep and replace multi line values in bash

Tags: sed, grep

How to uncomment the below lines efficiently from my config file.

```
#PPD=/home/mine/ppd (Line no. 100)
#_dco_ppd.c \
#       -DUSE_LIC -I$(LIC)/include -I$(LIC)/include/grok.c \
#       -L$(LIC)/lib -llic -lokta
```

I tried below options none worked

`grep -A 4 "PPD=/home/mine/ppd" config | xargs 0 sed -i 's/^#//g'` [threw below error]

**sed: invalid option -- 'D'
Usage: sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]...**

Other tries

```
sed -i 's|#PPD=/home/mine/ppd|PPD=/home/mine/ppd|' config (worked)
sed -i 's|#_dco_ppd.c|_dco_ppd.c|' config (worked)
sed -i 's|#       -DUSE_LIC|       -DUSE_LIC|' config (didnt work)
sed -i 's|#-DUSE_LIC|-DUSE_LIC|' config (didnt work as well)
```

Where am I going wrong ?

I'm on 14.04.1-Ubuntu Docker container

GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: when I try your attempt, `0` after `xargs` will throw `No such file or directory` error (but you got some other error).. in any case, you cannot pass grep results to sed in such a manner when you need to use inplace as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -Ei '/^#PPD/,/^#.*-lokta$/{s/#//}' configfile
```

Look for the text required in your sed statement

/^#PPD/ - line beginning with (^) #PPD to (signified by ,) ...

/^#.*-lokta$/ - line beginning with (^) #, then anything, then -lokta, end of line ($)

Then execute the substitution enclosed within {}

Comment: Good one. suggestion: `-E` and `{}` grouping isn't needed here and `s/^#//` would be more robust

Comment: Fair point but I think curly braces help readability.

Comment: agree. another suggestion would be `sed '/^#PPD/,+3 s/^#//'` since number of lines seems to be fixed.. and OP likely has `GNU sed` based on `-i` usage and `Ubuntu Docker`

Comment: @RamanSailopal : Wow, worked like a charm.
Can you please explain once the purpose of ,/^#.*

Comment: @Goku see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-print-lines-between-two-patterns-inclusive-or-exclusive-in-sed-awk-or

Comment: @SUndeep : Appreciate your help and time :) thanks for the suggestion